# converting dtype of numpy array changes its contents/values

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

```py
>>>import numpy as np
>>>np.__version__
'1.18.5'

>>>a = np.linspace(202012121024, 202012131024, dtype=np.float64).reshape(5,5,2)
>>>a[0, 0, 0]
202012121024.0

>>>int(a[0, 0, 0])
202012121024

>>>b = a.astype('float32')
>>>b[0, 0, 0]
202012110000.0         

>>>int(b[0, 0, 0])
202012114944
```

Why do the values change first by simply changing the dtype of `a` and assigning it to `b` and then even for `b`, if I change its one value to `int`, the actual value which is converted to `integer` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you set `b` to `a.astype('float32')` try instead `a.astype('float64')` and assign it to `b` then the value of `a and b` will be the same.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(202012121024, 202012131024, dtype=np.float64).reshape(5,5,2)
print(a[0, 0, 0])
print(int(a[0, 0, 0]))
b = a.astype('float64')
print(b[0, 0, 0]
```

**Output**

```
202012121024.0
202012121024
202012121024.0
```

Comment: Is `float32` not able to handle this value? I have to change the array to 32 bit because of memory constraints. Is there no other way to convert the array type to  `float32`?

Comment: @AtherCheema `float32` is a 32-bit number - `float64` uses a 64-bits number. The number you have set in np is a long float value. Hence it must be needed to store the value in a 64bit approch.